# Remove Parent Theme Settings From Child Theme

Tags: 8

I'm in the middle of creating a custom theme using the `Bootstrap` theme as it's parent. As you may, or may not be aware, the `Bootstrap` theme comes with lots of useful theme settings. These are great, but as this custom theme will be used for a client, most of these settings could be dangerous for them to be able to change.

I'd like to remove all of these theme settings, so only the ones I add in my custom theme will appear.

I know these theme settings would still be available to change in the `Bootstrap` theme, but that's not a problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This definitely isn't the nicest solution, but it does work. If you find a better one, do post it here.

```
function THEMENAME_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface &$form_state, $form_id = NULL) {
  unset($form['global']);
  unset($form['bootstrap']);
  unset($form['general']);
  unset($form['theme_settings']);
  unset($form['logo']);
  unset($form['favicon']);
  unset($form['components']);
  unset($form['update']);
  unset($form['javascript']);
  unset($form['advanced']);
}
```

Comment: A note on this approach - if your theme relies upon any settings defined in those form elements, the settings effectively get wiped. So, 2 solutions - either make sure your child theme does not rely upon any of those settings, or set some defaults for these values in your hook.